# tensorflow: change in parameter weights is different than it should be based on gradients

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-gradient

EDIT: Solved -- it was the stupidity of using different training examples for the gradients vs the optimizer update.

OK this has me totally stumped.

I have a parameter vector, let's call it **w**.

> **w** = [-1.34554319,  0.86998659,  0.52366061,  2.6723526 ,  0.18756115,
>           0.16547382]

I use `compute_gradients` to figure out the gradients to **w**, it tells me the gradient is:

> **dw** = [-0.0251517 ,  0.88050844,  0.80362262,  0.14870925,  0.10019595,
>            1.33597524]

My learning rate is `0.1`. Ergo:

> w_new = w - 0.1 * dw
>
> w_new = [-1.34302802,  0.78193575,  0.44329835,  2.65748168,  0.17754156,
>           0.0318763 ]

You can check the math yourself but it should check out. However, if I run the tensorflow code and evaluate the value of `w_new`, I get:

> w_new_tf = [-1.27643258,  0.9212401 ,  0.09922112,  2.55617223,  0.38039282, 0.15450044]

I honestly have no idea why it's doing this.

Edit: Let me provide you the exact code to show you why it doesn't work. It might be due to indexing, as you will see.

Here is the boilerplate starter code.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

max_item = 331922
max_user = 1581603
k = 6
np.random.seed(0)
_item_biases = np.random.normal(size=max_item)
np.random.seed(0)
_latent_items = np.random.normal(size=(max_item, k))
np.random.seed(0)
_latent_users = np.random.normal(size=(max_user, k))

item_biases = tf.Variable(_item_biases, name='item_biases')
latent_items = tf.Variable(_latent_items, name='latent_items')
latent_users = tf.Variable(_latent_users, name='latent_users')

input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[3], name='input_data')
```

Here is the custom objective function.

```
def objective(data, lam, item_biases, latent_items, latent_users):  
    with tf.name_scope('indices'):
        user = data[0]
        rated_item = data[1]
        unrated_item = data[2]

    with tf.name_scope('input_slices'):
        rated_item_bias = tf.gather(item_biases, rated_item, name='rated_item_bias')
        unrated_item_bias = tf.gather(item_biases, unrated_item, name='unrated_item_bias')

        rated_latent_item = tf.gather(latent_items, rated_item, name='rated_latent_item')
        unrated_latent_item = tf.gather(latent_items, unrated_item, name='unrated_latent_item')

        latent_user = tf.gather(latent_users, user, name='latent_user')

    with tf.name_scope('bpr_opt'):
        difference = tf.subtract(rated_item_bias, unrated_item_bias, 'bias_difference')
        ld = tf.subtract(rated_latent_item, unrated_latent_item, 'latent_item_difference')
        latent_difference = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(ld, latent_user), name='latent_difference')
        total_difference = tf.add(difference, latent_difference, name='total_difference')

    with tf.name_scope('obj'):        
        obj = tf.sigmoid(total_difference, name='activation')
    with tf.name_scope('regularization'):
        reg = lam * tf.reduce_sum(rated_item_bias**2)
        reg += lam * tf.reduce_sum(unrated_item_bias**2) 
        reg += lam * tf.reduce_sum(rated_latent_item**2) 
        reg += lam * tf.reduce_sum(unrated_latent_item**2)
        reg += lam * tf.reduce_sum(latent_user**2)

    with tf.name_scope('final'):
        final_obj = -tf.log(obj) + reg


    return final_obj
```

Here is some boilerplate code to actually minimize the function. At two points I do a `sess.run` call on the `tf.Variable`s to see how the values have changed.

```
obj = objective(input_data, 0.05, item_biases, latent_items, latent_users)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)
trainer = optimizer.minimize(obj)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())


citem_biases, clatent_items, clatent_users = \
    sess.run([item_biases, latent_items, latent_users])

print (clatent_users[1490103]) # [-1.34554319, 0.86998659, 0.52366061, 2.6723526 , 0.18756115, 0.16547382]

cvalues = sess.run([trainer, obj], feed_dict={input_data:[1490103, 278755, 25729]})
citem_biases, clatent_items, clatent_users = \
    sess.run([item_biases, latent_items, latent_users]) 
print (clatent_users[1490103]) #[-1.27643258,  0.9212401 ,  0.09922112,  2.55617223,  0.38039282, 0.15450044]
```

Finally, here is some code to actually get the gradients. These gradients are double checked against a hand-derived gradients so they are correct. Sorry for the ugliness of the code, it's a blatant copy & paste of another SO answer:

```
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(obj, tf.trainable_variables())
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
gradients_and_vars = sess.run(grads_and_vars, feed_dict={input_data:[1490103, 278830, 140306]})
print (gradients_and_vars[2][0]) #[-0.0251517 ,  0.88050844,  0.80362262,  0.14870925,  0.10019595, 1.33597524]
```

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example

Comment: Alright, I added my entire code. It's not pretty, but there could be a million things in my code that cause this issue (bugs or tensorflow issues) so I've gone ahead and posted the entire thing.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide complete code, but I ran a similar example and it did work for me as it should. Here is my code:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
  ph = tf.constant([1., 2., 3.])
  v = tf.get_variable('v', (3,))
  loss = tf.square(ph-v)
  optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)
  trainer = optimizer.minimize(loss)
  gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)[0][0]

  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    grad_mat = sess.run(gradients)
    v_0 = sess.run(v)
    sess.run(trainer)
    v_1 = sess.run(v)

    print(grad_mat)
    print(v_0)
    print(v_0 - 0.1*grad_mat)
    print(v_1)
```

Here is the output (obviously it will be a bit different each time, due to the random initialization of get_variable):

```
[-2.01746035 -5.61006117 -6.7561307 ]
[-0.00873017 -0.80503058 -0.37806535]
[ 0.19301586 -0.24402446  0.29754776]
[ 0.19301586 -0.24402446  0.29754776]
```

The last two lines are identical, as you would expect.

Comment: Sure thing. I added the full extent of my code. I suspect it's not a simple gradient descent problem (one would certainly hope not!) but perhaps an issue when you deal with sparse slicing and such. Try running the code I have at the top and let me know if you run into the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

Problem: I was feeding different inputs for gradients vs. the trainer.
Solution: Feed the same input.